# Python: .count() doesn't count

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple program that takes user input and prints the number of even, odd and zeros.

The program doesn't yield any errors but it seems to skip line 5 and 15
I want to count and display the zeroes in the `numbers` list

```
numbers = input("Numbers seperated by space:").split()
 
print("Numbers:" + str(numbers))
 
zero = numbers.count(0)
even = 0
odd = 0
 
for i in numbers:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
 
even = even - zero
 
print("Even:" + str(even))
print("Odd:" + str(odd))
print("Zero:" + str(zero))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre code isnt working because inputs in Python are strings. So when you enter a number like 5, Python turns it into "5". So to make your code work change .count(0) to .count("0")

```py
numbers = input("Numbers seperated by space:").split()
 
print("Numbers:" + str(numbers))
 
zero = numbers.count("0")
even = 0
odd = 0
 
for i in numbers:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
 
even = even - zero
 
print("Even:" + str(even))
print("Odd:" + str(odd))
print("Zero:" + str(zero))
```

Output:

```
Numbers seperated by space:
5 0 0 2
Numbers:['5', '0', '0', '2']
Even:1
Odd:1
Zero:2
```

If you are sure that only numbers are the input you could also do

```py
numbers = [int(elem) for elem in input("Numbers seperated by space:").split()]
zero = numbers.count(0)
```

Comment: Just for reference you can't cast a list of string to a list of int directly as shown at the end of the answer you have to cast each element to int, so something like `[int(elem) for elem in input("Numbers seperated by space:").split()]`

Answer (score 0):

When counting evens, zeros may get added so I would check for this condition first

```
numbers = input("Numbers separated by space:").split()
 
print("Numbers:" + str(numbers))
 
zero = 0
even = 0
odd = 0
 
for i in numbers:
    if int(i) == 0:
        zero += 1
    elif int(i) % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1

# using f-string to format output instead
print(f"Even: {even}")
print(f"Odd: {odd}")
print(f"Zero: {zero}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = input("Numbers separated by space:").split()

zero = numbers.count("0")
even = 0
odd = 0

for i in numbers:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0 and i != '0':
        even +=1
    elif int(i) %2 !=0 and i != '0':
        odd +=1

print("Even:" + str(even))
print("Odd:" + str(odd))
print("Zero:" + str(zero))
```